# Responsive columns with AngularJS (and no jQuery)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

this feels like a really daft question because it should be so easy but I've been trying to figure it out for a day or two now!
I'm trying to build a fully AngularJS app without jQuery and a couple of tricks are proving hard than I imagined.

I've got a three column layout, all within one scope using a Bootstrap layout. Left and right columns show on desktop and disappear on tablet and mobile.
Two buttons toggle those columns in and out when viewing on mobile/tablet.

That's literally it! But I want to do it the AngularJS way rather than jQuery - which would be super simple, by checking the class or style and toggling show or hide.

In AngularJS, if I use ng-show or ng-hide, and toggling a variable with ng-click then they are either shown on tablet/mobile by default (they need to be hidden) or they are hidden on the desktop by default (need to be shown).

I've done quite a lot of AngularJS work, so this is making me feel a bit stupid - I have no problem with internationalisation, localisation, localStorage support etc but this one has me stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably hiding your outer columns with `hidden-xs` or similar classes. You could simply add those classes by default, but remove them on demand through the `ng-class` directive:

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{'hidden-xs' : !showLeft}">
  <h3>Left</h3>
</div>
```

Your controller would then add the responsive class by default:

```
function ColumnController( $scope ) {
  $scope.showLeft = false;
  $scope.showRight = false;
}
```

You can take a look at this on: http://plnkr.co/edit/s2sjC53EJNZEKpf4jRFr?p=preview

Comment: @ChrisSoutham It's actually even simpler than I originally suggested. I've updated my answer.